# How to drop Primary key thats needed in a foreign key constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, cascade

I want to drop the primary key in **father**. So I set the foreign key in **child** to delete cascade. Why this doesnt work ? Do I need to delete the **foreign key** first ? If so, then what the propurse of the delete on cascade statement ?

```
create database table_test;

use table_test;

create table father(
cod int, 
primary key (cod)
);

create table child(
cod int,
cod_father int,
primary key(cod),
constraint fk_cod_father foreign key (cod_father) references father(cod)
on delete cascade
);

alter table father
drop primary key;
```

Comment: Drop FK then drop PK.

Comment: Delete cascade is on data level not table definition. If you delete a father then also his children are deleted.

Comment: "drop" (changes database structure) is different from "deleting" (only changes data). What exactly do you want?

Comment: @maraca This is relevant knowledge that I didn't know. I thought deleting on cascade was at table structure level. Thanks.

Comment: @TheImpaler I did not know that on cascade was only apply for deleting data and not to delete tables. My thoughts was that if I delete fathers table automatically the  foreign key in the child were be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, find, present & justify the smallest wrong code--code that doesn't do what you expect--that is an extension of correct code--code that does what you expect. Say what you expect & why, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) Otherwise you're just asking for yet another definition & presentation for you to misunderstand, with no details of your misconceptions. [mre] [ask] Plus for basic problems those will be faqs you can then characterize specifically enough to (re)search & find. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ON DELETE CASCADE constraint is used in MySQL to delete the rows from
> the child table automatically, when the rows from the parent table are
> deleted

You want to remove primary key and in your case first you need to unlink the foreign key reference. So drop foreign key first.